# RoR, localhost server working but not achievable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, localhost

Forgive me please that newbie question.
So, I recently started with RoR. As one of the first steps given, there is creation of a server.

[Communicat after creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3VEj.jpg) seems well, but next one on the same photo, wget, inform us, that server is impossible to achieve. 
I find it not reasonable, I feel like i tried everything, while it is very basic function!

Comment: We need more information. Can you show us the exact steps that you took and the exact error messages (if any) that you see?

Answer (score 2):

The server did not start because it tried to create a directory `tmp/pids` and it failed. Make sure the user you are running as has permission to write in the `tmp` directory. Then restart the server.